# Share data retrieved using HttpClient between Angular components

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-services

I would like to create a service method which at first execution will fetch a dataset from an URL, cache the dataset, and then share the same instance of the dataset with the components which subsequently call the service method.

I have started creating two solutions. The problem with both solutions is that in the first milliseconds after loading the Angular app, they fetch the dataset from the URL multiple times, and/or they throw some error messages to the console, but after the first or second navigation between the two components, the data seems to be shared correctly, and there is no more roundtrip to the URL.

Approach #1

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FirstService {
  private url = 'http://somedummydomain.com/api/entries';
  private data: any;
  private observable: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData() : Observable<any> {
    if (this.data) {
      return of(this.data);
    } else if (this.observable) {
      return this.observable;
    } else {
      this.observable = this.http.get(this.url);
      this.observable.subscribe((data) => {
        this.data = data;
        this.observable = null;
      });
      return this.observable;
    }
  }
}
```

Approach #2

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SecondService {
  private sharedData: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  private url = 'http://somedummydomain.com/api/entries';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((data) => {
      this.addData(data);
    });
  }

  private addData(data: any) {
    this.sharedData.next(data);
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.sharedData.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Lib versions

- angular: v9.1.9
- rxjs: v6.5.5

Thanks!

Comment: There is basically no reason why the HTTP call should be made multiple times... Could you place `console.log` in the constructor of `SecondService`  and verify that it's only called once?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I actually had a mistake in the HTML file, which resulted in the console error message. But I would still appreciate if I could get the first approach working, because I later need to add the ReloadFromUrl and SaveDataToUrl functionality to the service, and the first approach seems less obscure to me, because it explicitly contains the "data" property.

Comment: `data` in Approach 1 is `sharedData.value` in Approach 2. I'd continue with Approach 2, because it contains less logic. However, the "reactive" way of doing this is neither of the two. But I suspect the "reactive" approach would be even more "obscure" ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, here is the *reactive* style of solving your requirement (**sharing data across subscribers**):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SecondService {
  private url = 'http://somedummydomain.com/api/entries';
  private data$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.data$ = this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.data$;
  }
}
```

The `shareReplay` operator will do two things:

1. It will **share** the Observable - that means that all subscribers will receive the same notifications and the source is subscribed to only once. Approach 1 fails for you, because each subscriber will trigger HTTP GET again until the first request completes and you get to your `this.data !== undefined` branch.
2. It will **replay** the last N notifications (in this case only the last notification) to all subscribers that came too late to the party - i.e. that subscribed after the HTTP call already returned a value. If you don't need this, use `share` instead.

If you need `data` as a property, you can set it with a `tap` operator like this:

```
this.data$ = this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
  tap(data => this.data = data),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you need to fetch a data from a url and share it between components. Why don't you fetch the data before loading the component? If fetching the data before loading the app is fine with you then you can use  **app-initializer**

> https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-the-app-initializer-token-to-hook-into

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be an interesting possibility, but I need to be able to occasionally reload the entire (shared) data set from the server, so this approach is not sufficient for me.